# Package 'cgroupfs-mount' has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I'm trying to install docker ce on wsl on windows home version 17134.765 (18.3). I'm following the directions in the screenshot after installing wsl with ubuntu 18.04 from https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2291#issuecomment-477632663. It seems to be working until the line:

```
  ~$  sudo apt -y install cgroupfs-mount
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 Package cgroupfs-mount is not available, but is referred to by another  package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

 E: Package 'cgroupfs-mount' has no installation candidate
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The same issue. But I found `cgroupfs-mount` is not necessary. I run the follow command, then start docker successfully!

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```